# Create weighted average in SQL using dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL query that lists details about a certain item. Everything works as should except for the last column. I want the `weight of transaction` column to report back a difference in days.

So for example the 4th row in the `txdate` column is 05/21/2014 and the 3rd row is 05/12/20014. The `weight of transaction` column in the 4th row should say 9.

I read about the Lag and Lead functions, but I'm not sure how to implement those with dates (if it's even possible). If it isn't possible is there a way to accomplish this?

[image: SQL results]

```
Select t.txNumber, 
   t.item, 
   t.txCode, 
   t.txdate, 
   (t.onhandlocold + t.stockQty) as 'Ending Quantity',
   tmax.maxtnumber 'Latest Transaction Code',
   tmax.maxdate 'Latest Transaction Date', 
   tmin.mindate 'First Transaction Date', 
   (t.txdate - tmin.mindate) 'weight of transaction'

From tbliminvtxhistory t
 Left outer join
     (Select t.item, max(t.txnumber) as maxtnumber, max(t.txdate) as maxdate
      From tbliminvtxHistory t
      Where t.txCode != 'PAWAY'
      Group By Item) tmax
  on t.item = tmax.item
Left Outer Join
     (Select t.item, min(t.txdate) as mindate
      From tbliminvtxHistory t
      WHere  t.txCode != 'PAWAY'
         and t.txdate > DateAdd(Year, -1, GetDate())
      Group By Item) tmin
  on t.item = tmin.item

where t.item = 'LR50M' 
and t.txCode != 'PAWAY'
and t.txdate > DateAdd(Year, -1, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function, which will return the difference between two dates.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
DATEDIFF(dd,tmin.mindate,t.txdate)
```

**UPDATE:**

Now that I understand your question a little better, here is an update. As mentioned in a comment on the above post, the [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function is only supported in SQL 2012 and up. An alternative is to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and store the results into a temp table. Then you can left join back to the same table on the next `ROW_NUMBER` in the results. Then you would use your `DATEDIFF` to compare the dates. This will do the exact same thing as the the `LAG` function.

Example:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY txdate) AS RowNumber,*
INTO #Rows
FROM tbliminvtxhistory 

SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,r2.txdate,r.txdate),* 
FROM #Rows r
LEFT JOIN #Rows r2 ON r.RowNumber=r2.RowNumber+1

DROP TABLE #Rows
```

Comment: Yes. It works, however I do have one question. Is there a way to use that to compare dates in pairs? Like take the first two dates and see if there is a date difference, and then compare the third to the second, fourth to the third, and then post a weighted difference between the compared dates?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. When you say "third to the second", and "fourth to the third" are you talking about additional columns that aren't in your example? If so, you can add multiple datediff calls together and divide by the number of calls.

Comment: No, not additional columns. When this is ran it shows the difference in days to the very first txdate `05/12/14`. I want it to compare to the previous txdate sequentially. The first txdate has nothing to compare to, so it is 0. The second txdate compares to the first and returns 0 because there is no change. The third txdate compares to the second txdate and returns 0 because there isn't a difference, however the fourth txdate is `05/21/14` so it will return a 9 because there were 9 days between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this expression:

```
Select . . . ,
       datediff(day, lag(txdate) over (order by xnumber), txdate)
```

This assumes that the rows are ordered by the first column, which seems reasonable given your explanation and the sample data.

EDIT:

Without `lag()` you can use `outer apply`.  For simplicity, let me assume that your query is defined as a CTE:

```
with cte as (<your query here>)
select . . . ,
       datediff(day, prev.txdate , cte.txdate)
from cte cross apply
     (select top 1 cte2.*
      from cte cte2
      where cte2.xnumber < cte.xnumber
      order by cte2.xnumber desc
     ) prev
```

Comment: Is there a method to do this without using lag? I applied it and it turns out we run on SQL server 2008, not 2012.